# What is the User Picker behaviour for leaving people?

Tags: google-app-maker

App Maker has a [User Picker widget](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/input-widgets#user-picker) that connects to the domain directory (nice) but the documentation says nothing about what happens when a user goes missing.

The obvious example is an employee leaving the company and being deleted after some safe period (3 months for us).

What would happend in the App Maker application in such case when there are records that the User Picker based field points to a user that no longer exists?

Super crash? Validation problems? Random ugly numeric ID shown instead of the old username?

Has anyone faced this?

thanks,
marc

Comment: The user picker is integrated with the directory model, which is integrated with the directory api; therefore if the user is deleted, it won't appear in the user picker anymore.

Comment: I guessed that part. My wonder is, when somebody is editing an entry that now contains an invalid user, will they be able to save? or will they start seing validation errors because the user no longer exists?